# Get git commit id for C# .Net Core Application

Tags: git, .net-core, .net-assembly, webapi

I'm working for a .NET Core web api application. My requirement is to show repository's (Bitbucket) latest **local git commit id** of in the home controller. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: git commit id of what? The controller does not know that it's source was under version control. Maybe you can have your build pipeline write it to a configuration or source file before compiling?

Comment: Below is the local git commit id "b5519c35cd99cab61e9e8b6357a76ad05d272ca8" which I'm able to see in the git console using the comment "git describe --long". I need this id need to get in api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have solutions like :

- https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning
- https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion

that populate your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file with some data linked to git and that you can use in your code and so display it.

The other solution is indeed to get it with a git command line and, maybe the more convenient, generate a partial class and add the generated file in the `.gitignore` file.

And then, here again, you could use the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Modify your build script to query the Git commit ID

   - There are many different options, depending on how your building your app.
   - EXAMPLE: `MSVS > Project > Properties > Build Events > Pre-build event command line`
2. The script needs to write the commit ID somewhere.
3. Your C# app needs to read the commit ID somehow. EXAMPLE:

   - Write to file `git-info.txt`
   - Check your project properties and ensure that the git-info.txt file is copied in your app's build
   - Write the code to read and display it at runtime: [MSDN: How to read from a text file (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file)

Comment: For me the best is to generate a file compiled in the application.

Comment: The key issue is that you need *something* in your "build pipeline" to 1) read the value from Git, and then 2) write that value somewhere for C#.  I suggested "MSVS Build Events" as one possibility.  If happen to be using [BitBucket CI/CD pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines), you have many other options.  You can easily have a C# .cs source file with the text `@@GIT_ID@@` in it, and then have your "build script" (whatever you decide) do a text substitution with the "real" Git commit ID.